Konjunktiv II für irreale Vergleiche
Related:
Als mit Konjunktiv II (Irreale Vergleiche)
In the following example:
Es gibt eine Krise. 

When used with Konjunktiv II, is this correct?
Der Präsident tut so, als ob eine Krise wäre.

or:
Der Präsident tut so, als ob eine Krise gegeben hätte.

or both are wrong?
Der Präsident tut so …

is given and cannot be changed.

What is Konjunktiv II of "es gibt"?

You have to retain the verb geben. So it's

Der Präsident tut so, als ob es eine Krise gibt. (Indikativ Präsens)
Der Präsident tut so, als ob es eine Krise gäbe. (Konjunktiv II)
Der Präsident tut so, als ob es eine Krise geben würde. (Konjunktiv II Futur I)

That latter form is a drop-in replacement for Konjunktiv II. You can use it with all verbs but for the common strong verbs as geben the Konjunktiv II form is more common.


Der Präsident tut so, als ob eine Krise wäre.

This does not retain the verb geben. It's understandable but not the common way to express this. The verb geben has to be used for there is in German.

Der Präsident tut so, als ob es eine Krise gegeben hätte.

This is Konjunktiv II Perfekt. It's about a crisis in the past therefore.

Der Präsident tut so, als ob es eine Krise gegeben hat. (Indikativ Perfekt)
Der Präsident tut so, als ob es eine Krise gegeben hätte. (Konjunktiv II Perfekt)
Der Präsident tut so, als ob es eine Krise gegeben haben würde. (Konjunktiv II Futur II)

This latter form again may be used as a drop-in replacement for Konjunktiv II Perfekt but it's really uncommon. Instead, the Perfekt auxiliary haben or sein is put in Konjunktiv II.

You are missing the 'es' in the sentence with 'wäre'. I would also say 'wäre' is grammatically correct and fine to use, it just has a different meaning that 'gäbe'. With the Verb gäbe, the crisis is universal all around us, with wäre this would be talking about a specific event which could be considered a crisis or not.

The es was missing in the original example. I quoted the original example.

@quarague Yep, you're right. 'es' should be there
